# Makefile target with wildcard to create symlink using target string

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I'd like a set of makefile rules that create a symlink to one of several code modules before building the project. The name of the make target would determine the file to which the symlink points. For example:

- The user invokes 'make R3000'
- Make sees that 'data.asm' doesn't exist yet, so a symlink is created from 'data_R3000.asm' to 'data.asm'
- The build process continues, using data.asm

How can I set up make rules to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
MODULES := $(patsubst data_%.asm,%,$(wildcard data_*.asm))

all:
    ...

data.asm:
        [ -n "$(filter $(MAKECMDGOALS),$(MODULES))" ] || { echo unknown module: $(MAKECMDGOALS) ; exit 1; }
        ln -s $(filter $(MAKECMDGOALS),$(MODULES)) $@
```

Then make sure `data.asm` is listed as a prerequisite in the appropriate rules.

Comment: Something like this is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
.PHONY mklink

mklink:
    test -e data_$(MAKECMDGOALS).asm || exit 1
    ln -s data_$(MAKECMDGOALS).asm data.asm
```

and then make all (and other targets) dependent on mklink.  The reason you shouldn't make data.asm your target in the rule is that if you run `make R3000`, then data.asm will be created, and then if you run `make L2000`, the data.asm file will be pointing to the wrong directory, and will not be overwritten (I'll assuming this is not what you want).  The test line checks if the link target exists, and if not, it exits with 1, causing the target to fail.  You should also add a check that MAKECMDGOALS is exactly one element as well.